# Name for DIY Electronics as a hobby

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any specific word for self made electronics as a hobby?

I have seen some people expressing this with popular brand names such as Arduino or Raspberry Pi.

My only idea so far is "DIY Electronics", but it does not feel quite right.

Comment: DIY electronics is actually used : https://www.google.it/#q=diy+electronic+projects

Comment: They are called *makers*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maker_culture

Comment: Back when I did that sort of stuff I simply called myself an "electronics hobbyist".

Comment: Makers also include metalworkers and woodworkers. For a more specific term try [*hardware hacker*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_%28hobbyist%29)?

Comment: DIY could mean someone who repairs factory-built electronics rather than builds their own, but it depends on context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AmE you can make most things into a hobby by using the word "***buff***" in conjunction with them:

- Antique Car Buff
- Exotic Food Buff
- Electronics Buff

It may be a bit old-fashioned, but I think the meaning is still more precisely conveyed than with something like "*DIY Electronics*" - which could simply mean that you've stolen your neighbor's cable TV.

Comment: But a "buff" might be just an _aficionado_ (that is, an onlooker rather than a participant).

Comment: True... but I think it still implies some level of knowledge or expertise, while DIY has as many negative connotations as positive ones.